# AWK print next line of match between matches

Tags: awk

Let's presume I have file test.txt with following data:

```
.0
41
0.0
42
0.0
43
0.0
44
0.0
45
0.0
46
0.0
START
90
34
17
34
10
100
20
2056
30
0.0
10
53
20
2345
30
0.0
10
45
20
875
30
0.0
END
0.0
48
0.0
49
0.0
140
0.0
```

With AWK how would I print the lines after 10 and 20 between START and END.
So the output would be.

```
100
2056
53
2345
45
875
```

I was able to get the lines with 10 and 20 with

```
awk '/START/,/END/ {if($0==10 || $0==20) print $0}' test.txt
```

but how would I get the next lines?

Answer (score 2):

I actually got what I wanted with

```
awk '/^START/,/^END/ {if($0==10 || $0==20) {getline; print} }' test.txt
```

Comment: Another way `awk 'x;/START/,/END/{if(x||/^(10|20)$/)x=!x}' file`

Comment: @JID Works but less readable. And can be shorten some `^(1|2)0$`

Comment: @Jotne `^(1|2)0$` actually does damage readability though as is it less obvious what you are searching for especially if large numbers were used.

Answer (score 1):

Range in `awk` works fine, but is less flexible than using flags.

```
awk '/^START/ {f=1} /^END/ {f=0} f && /^(1|2)0$/ {getline;print}' file
100
2056
53
2345
45
875
```

Comment: This will match anything with 10 or 20 in it such as 100.

Comment: @JID Fixed befor you comment was posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ranges as they make trivial things slightly briefer but require a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions when things get even slightly more complicated.

Don't use getline unless it's an appropriate application and you have read and fully understand http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Just let awk read your lines as designed:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/START/  { inBlock=1 }
/END/    { inBlock=0 }
foundTgt { print; foundTgt=0 }
inBlock && /^[12]0$/ { foundTgt=1 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
100
2056
53
2345
45
875
```

Feel free to use single-character variable names and cram it all onto one line if you find that useful:

```
awk '/START/{b=1} /END/{b=0} f{print;f=0} b&&/^[12]0$/{f=1}' file
```

Comment: I actually find the single line easier to understand. Also whilst `^[12]0$` saves a character or two i find that /^(10|20)$/ makes it clearer what you are searching for, especially if the numbers were larger or there were lots.

Comment: horses for courses I suppose. I find `^[12]0$` clearer. Oh well.